# CSS spontaneous changes, bug?

Tags: html, css

Lately the layout on my website has changed spontaneously without me doing anything. For example: [some text has been heavily misplaced and small circles are appearing in strange places.](https://gyazo.com/bb6069d4de568c902e8526864b5f5f2f).

The weird part is that it can't be changed - no matter what I change in CSS, the changes aren't displayed on my website. I could literally erase the entire .css content and save it, and it would still show the same website with slightly misplaced objects. If I, however, were to remove the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="luffisdesign.css"/>
```

tag from my HTML code, it would remove the CSS layout completely. What's happening?

**update**
Image didn't display, here's a link: gyazo.com/bb6069d4de568c902e8526864b5f5f2f The "- - -" part was originally placed in the grey area with the form underneath. I have made absolutely zero changes in both of the documents since it displayed properly

Comment: add link to your website to get help.

Comment: It's a localhost. I could attach the code of my work but I think the problem lays with CSS or Chrome itself.

Comment: CSS *is* code, so include it (and html too)

Comment: forward your port 80 in the router and create a [free dynamic DNS](http://www.duckdns.org/)

Comment: Don't just forward ports and open your local computer to the general public. If you do, at least research & understand the security risks implied with doing so. A much better solution is getting something like Digital Ocean for $5/mo; Or create a jsfiddle or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your site isn't grabbing the most recent version of the stylesheet because the one being shown is a cached version. You can append ?v=(x value) to the end of the link to grab the stylesheet, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="luffisdesign.css?v=1"/>
```

Alternatively, you could use `?t=<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>` if you're using php.

Wanted to leave a comment instead of a reply since this doesn't answer your concern about the random circles, but can't since I don't have 50 rep yet.

Comment: Just a note for people who don't know: The `?v` or `?t` parts don't mean anything. You could do `?meow=panda1` and it would have the same affect. The idea behind doing this, is simply that you're changing the URL. Since the URL has changed, the browser doesn't cache it because it thinks that it is new & hasn't been downloaded before

Comment: Did not know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you updated your browser your something.

Typically, when CSS gets 'stuck' it means there is some kind of caching going on. Try removing the CSS, and opening up an private browsing session and see if that works.

On Chrome, in the developer tools you can disable caching, and you can also ctrl+f5 which sometimes helps with caching.

If you're doing server side caching, then query parameters like `mystyle.css?v=1` works really well for caching busting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers! Like Kenyon said, it might be because I recently updated my browser. Didn't think of that. I managed to solve my problem by simply transfering the text in my .css file to a new document and linking the new document to the HTML code instead. I have no idea why that solved it since they both contain the exact same file, but somehow it did.

Comment: Like myself & Daniel Gomez said, it has to do with caching. Your browser cached (saved offline, basically) your CSS file. So even though you were changing it, the browser was never asking for it, because it assumed it already had the CSS file.